# Trigger event with RDP login

Tags: windows-10, rdp, taskscheduler, event-viewer

I'm running Win 10 without running explorer.exe
At startup windows runs my default app, but I need to run explorer.exe whenever a RDP connection is done to the machine.

I'm been trying to find the RDP success login event to use in Task Scheduler, but have no look.

How to find the event to fill the fields Log:, Source: and Event ID: on Task Scheduler?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it, actually its kind of simple.

Using Computer Management -> Event Viewer -> Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager -> Admin and here you can see the last events, ID 20521 seems to be RDP login, not sure about this.
Right click and select Attach Task To This Event, from here configure Task Scheduler accordingly with your needs.

Don't know if there is a better way do do this, but it works for me.